# Disable caching from the client side in OkHttp

Tags: android, okhttp

In Volley, there is a simple `NoCache` class within the toolbox which disables all network caching. The class is just an extension of the Volley cache which doesn't call through to any supers.

Curious if theres a simple way with OkHttp to do this?

A method I have seen is writing an interceptor which adds a no-cache header to the responses, but it seems odd to modify the request/response instead of just not having a cache at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure this in a header on outgoing requests, in an interceptor, or by simply not setting a cache on your OkHttpClient.

Comment: How the thought of simply not setting a cache at all didn't occur to me is wild. Thanks.